# Decrypting the signature created by RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData() to get the hash

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to retrieve the hash created with the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class' `SignData` and `SignHash` methods. I need this to be able to store encrypted hashes that must be retrieved later because they're part of a hash chain.

Initially I wanted to encrypt and decrypt hashes manually, using the private key for encryption, but the library doesn't allow it.

I can't find a method that does this, and all my searches have returned answers about how private key encryption is a bad idea (when not using it for signing ...).

Comment: The simplest solution is to hash the same data with the same algorithm. But you could also use `e^sig mod n` on the signature, and then follow the padding spec to extract the hash.

Comment: @Matej It's not clear what you are asking.  If you want to "encrypt and decrypt hashes" then you can simply encrypt the hash data--that's supported.  I'm not clear on why you'd want to encrypt a hash though...

Comment: I can't hash the same data because it's dependent on the previous hash, which needs to be decrypted first.
I basically want to sign the data, which is encrypting the hash. But with the private key. The `Encrypt` method uses the public key, though.