# C# Retrieve RSA Signed Data

Tags: c#, rsa

I have a signed hash sent by a server and I want to get this hash back on my client using the provided corresponding public key. But when I search the C# documentation especially the RSACryptoServiceProvider, I only find methods tu “Fully” verify the signature not just retrieving the hash ? Does anybody have a clue ?

Thanks in advance,

Edsdev

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601998/decrypting-the-signature-created-by-rsacryptoserviceprovider-signdata-to-get-t

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is exactly what I need !